# get data from onClick event/onClick event behavior

Tags: java, events, click, listener, onitemclick

I have been coding for a while but I never took any course, so I have some questions on how some things works. One of them is onClick listeners. I have a question about the onClick event, more precisely the onItemClick event.

Let's say I have a simple listView and I want to handle the onItemClick event, I would have something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

String parameter = "123";

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                // TODO1
            }

}
// TODO2
```

Is there a way to pass the value of 'item' so I can use it in 'TODO2'?

Also, if I had some stuff to do in TODO1 and needed the 'parameter' variable, is there a way to pass that into the onItemClick method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener is an anonymous inner class. It may use fields from surrounding class

2) parameter must be defined as a "final" variable.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    String final parameter = "123"; //<--

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); //<--
            // TODO1
            System.out.println(parameter)
        }

}
// TODO2

private String item = null;

public String getLastClickedItem(){
    return item;
}
```

Comment: I dont think anyone could've explained better! Thank you very much!